# Why does the hydride ion in LAH act as a nucleophile rather than a base in the reduction of carbonyl compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, nucleophilic-substitution

Why does the $\ce{H-}$ ion in $\ce{LiAlH4}$ act as a nucleophile rather than a base in the reduction of carbonyl compounds ??

Because $\ce{H-}$ being a small ion would act as a better base than a nucleophile and I have been taught that it mostly acts as a base and it is very rarely that it is a nucleophile.

Also $\ce{H-}$ after extracting $\ce{H+}$ should become $\ce{H2}$ and leave the system, and also favour this reaction and move it forward.

Comment: Heavily related, same answer and hence possible duplicate of [Why does a hydride like NaH act as a base, but a hydride like NaBH4 act as a nucleophile?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/why-does-a-hydride-like-nah-act-as-a-base-but-a-hydride-like-nabh4-act-as-a-nuc)

Comment: Because there is not actually ionic separation i.e H- is not formed.